# имя файла на кириллице в VSCode

Tags: кодировка, visual-studio-code, кириллица

В VSCode названия файлов на кириллице в терминале (терминал PS) отображаются цифрами. Создаю файл, называю его "Работа_со_строками.py". При отслеживании статуса в терминале идет сообщение, что нужно добавить в отслеживаемые файл "\320\240\320\260\320\261\320\276\321\202\320\260_\321\201\320\276_\321\201\321\202\321\200\320\276\320\272\320\260\320\274\320\270.py". Если добавлю, закоммичу, отправлю на Гитхаб, то там название файла превращается в параллельно-перпендикулярные черточки. Как исправить, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Используйте английские символы для имен файлов, так как это более стандартная и поддерживаемая практика. Также есть возможность переименовать файл на GitHub после его загрузки.

Comment: А у меня нормально отправляются русские буквы

Comment: Файл добавляй в коммит через плюсик мышкой - нормально добавляется

Comment: @DovgalDima, так я не против, так и делаю пока, но только гложет вопрос, ведь можно же исправить, чисто для понимания ответ нужен.

Comment: @eri , файл в коммит добавляется русскими буквами, а когда git status смотрю, тогда циферки получаются, ну и далее передаются на гитхаб черточками.